# Detect the function that redirects the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress

Huy guys,

This morning at work I stucked on a damn thing weird.

To see: http://csrepentigny.com it will redirect you to FIFA. We don't want this and it seems that it's a Javascript that is redirecting the page.

I tried using Google Dev Tools Timeline but I cannot find the specific line of code that does the redirect.

Does someone know how I can do that? Using Phantom.js or something else?

P.S.: The website is Wordpress powered.

Comment: There's a good chance we won't be able to see what's doing it. It may be server-side. Look for an .htaccess file on your server that contains a redirect.

Comment: I'm sure it's a JS 'cause I disabled it and it didn't redirect.

Comment: Ok. Try disabling the UJI Countdown Pro plugin.

Comment: Yah, found it. Little tricky malconfigured plugin from our client! That's why I don't debug other's website normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like the "Redirect to URL option after expiry" feature is enabled in **[UJI Countdown](https://wordpress.org/plugins/uji-countdown/)**. Try disabling that plugin.

Comment: Yes, it was indeed this!